# react Map is not returning any jsx

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looping over the people array and getting the first array. My screen should say "person 1". but it is blank and
nothing is being returned.

```
const people = [
    [
        {
            name: 'person 1'
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            name: 'person 2'
        }
    ],
]


export default function Index() {
    return (
        <>
            {people.slice(0,1).map((person) => {
                return <h1>{person.name}</h1>
            })}        
        </>
    )
}
```

the code works when i do this, but I need to use slice

```
export default function Index() {
    return (
        <>
            {people[0].map((person) => {
                return <h1>{person.name}</h1>
            })}        
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why is `people` a nested array? Why not simply `[{name: 'person 1'},{name: 'person 2'}]`?

Comment: @Phil i just used random dummy data to show the problem im facing

Comment: So what do you want the result to be? Just the first _person_ from the first array in _persons_? All the people in the first array? All the people in all arrays?

Comment: Having non-sensical data structures just makes developing and maintenance difficult. Clean up your data structures and you will have fewer problems

Comment: By the way, having a white screen in React usually means that your code errored, so React doesn't render; it's not that nothing was returned. Sometimes you'd consider using error boundaries.

Comment: @code OP probably has a `<h1></h1>` element. There's just no text because `[].name` is undefined

Comment: @Phil you're right, I saw wrong and thought there would be a cannot read properties of undefined error.

Comment: You can normalize/preprocess the array with `people.flat()`.

Answer (score 2):

`people.slice(0, 1)`, unlike you'd expect, returns `[[{ name: "person 1" }]]`, **not** `[{ name: "person 1" }]` (`Array#slice` returns a "slice" of an array, and in your special case it's an array with a single value, but not the single value itself). You'll have to access the inner array to get what you want:

```
// in your JSX
people.slice(0, 1).map(([person]) => (
  <h1>{person.name}</h1>
))
```

Notice that the argument destructures the input array (this assumes each value in `people` is an array with exactly one element; if not, loop over that content).

Another option would be to [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to "un-nest" those values:

```
// in your JSX
people.slice(0, 1).flatMap(person => (
  <h1>{person.name}</h1>
))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
 return (
        <>
            {people.slice(0,1).map((person) => {
                return <h1>{person[0].name}</h1>
            })}        
        </>
    )
```

Because each `person` is still an array, you can't access the object's properties directly without first accessing the array that wraps it.

Comment: that works .. but im confused.. (1)shouldn't people.slice(0,1) give me the first array and then im looping over that array with map which should give me direct access to the object?

Comment: no, the slice method as used will not return the first array inside your "parent" array. it will, as it should, slice your "parent" array so that the only element remaining inside it will be the first one, resulting in this array: [
    [
        {
            name: 'person 1'
        }
    ]
]

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the data structor of `people`.

```
const people = [
    {
        name: 'person 1'
    },
    {
        name: 'person 2'
    }
];
```

In you case, `person` in map method is `Array` type. So, `person.name`'s value will be `undefined`.